# package restore failed in visual studio 2015 after visual studio 2017 installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-1.0

I just installed visual studio 2017 enterprise edition on my system. But Now If I try to create any project using visual studio 2015, I see error in references section like this http://prntscr.com/et17ls

and output window shows this http://prntscr.com/et17qt

I see gloabl.json as this http://prntscr.com/et189h

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
  }
}
```

Please suggest how to fix it.

In my control panel, I see this http://prntscr.com/et18ws

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found solution. I need to update Tool preview for visual studio 2015. Here is what I wrote in detail https://asiftech.wordpress.com/2017/04/06/package-restore-failed-in-visual-studio-2015-after-visual-studio-2017-installation/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about asp.net core.

VS2015 and VS2017 are different. VS2015 uses project.json while VS2017 uses *.csproj

But you can convert it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj

And for myself, I just recreated in VS2017:
https://github.com/Longfld/ASPNETCoreAngular4

Comment: I don't want to convert a project. All I am saying is that now If I try to create any new project using visual studio 2015, It gives these errors.

Comment: As M$ has given up project.json to use **.csproj. IMO convert it will be better than fix it.